# Getting malloc-related error from design pattern of: malloc / free / malloc / free

Tags: c, malloc

I'm new to C, programming in Linux using gcc4.4.6 with switches `gcc -g -std=c89 -Wall ...`, and I'm getting this error many functions deep in my program named `compute`:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./compute: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000001a770b0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x366d475916]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x366d4786a4]
./compute[0x406987]
./compute[0x407f0d]
./compute[0x408a41]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x366d41ecdd]
./compute[0x401769]
======= Memory map: ========
...
```

Here's some pseudo-code (the code is very long, so I'm only showing the structure here):

```
myPts = 100;
JDP = malloc( sizeof(double) * myPts);
if (JDP == NULL)
   exit(27);
...
if (testCondition == 1) { /* my execution enters this if stmt here */
   ...
   myPts = 200;
   free(JDP);
   JDP = malloc (sizeof(double) * myPts);
   if (JDP == NULL)
      exit(27);
   myFunction(JDP, ...); /* array JDP is populated here */
   ...
 } else {
    JDP[0]=0;
 }
 myOtherFunction(..., JDP, ...); /* array JDP is used here */
 free(JDP); /* this line produces error shown above */
 return 0;
```

Stepping through the code using gdb, this error is produced on the 2nd line of code for: `free(JDP)`. The execution is such that array `JDP` is malloc'ed twice, with a free between them. Could this be the cause of the error? I've never done this before, and hoping there's some simple mistake I'm making...

UPDATE 1

Just wanted to specifically note that using gdb I do step the code through the first free and 2nd malloc, so I know the code passes through these steps.

If the design pattern above isn't a problem, what other scenarios would result in `free()` leading to this error?

Comment: Most propabyl `myFunction()` or `myOtherFunction()` are corrupting the memory pointed to by `JDP` or its neighbours. Run you app trough `valgrind` and you most certainly get enlighted ... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you have shown.  In particular the code pattern

```
x = malloc(n);
...
if (condition) {
    free(x); 
    x = malloc(m);
}
...
free(x);
```

is not wrong in and of itself.

You have almost certainly made a simple mistake somewhere in the code you did *not* show, which has caused memory corruption.  Fortunately there is an excellent tool for finding such mistakes automatically: it's called [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/).  Run your program under this tool.  Fix the *very first* error it tells you about.  Repeat until it tells you of no further errors.  (Often only the very first of valgrind's complaints reflects a real bug in your code; all the subsequent complaints are "merely" fallout from the original bad memory access.)

Comment: Having never used valgrind, is there a simple command I should use that you could point out to get me started in the right direction? From what I can read about it, it seems complicated to get started.

Comment: It has a whole lot of options, yeah, but for now you can ignore them all.  Just install it and do `valgrind ./YOURPROGRAM` instead of `./YOURPROGRAM`.  It may produce a whole lot of output.

Comment: Valgrind worked great, and is actually pretty easy to use. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Freeing the variable twice is fine so long as you're mallocing separately between them. I would suspect the issue is that you aren't actually mallocing between them - some logical switch (if/else/while) is preventing the `malloc` from taking place, thus the `free` occurs twice on the same pointer.

Comment: Setting pointers to `NULL` is generally used as a safeguard for the programmer - `free`ing one is still going to result in your program blowing up. However, it might make it easier to tell why your code is failing if you know it ought to be `NULL` and is not.

Comment: `free(NULL)` does not cause your program to blow up on standards-conforming implementations. C99 and POSIX both say, "If ptr is a null pointer, no action shall occur."

Comment: Interesting - for some reason I always thought it would. Thanks for the correction.